# add sup tag in ul li goes next line

Tags: html, css

I try to make one list with new label. it come ok when text is less. but my new label come in next line if text are more.  my code are as follows:

```
<ul>
   <li> text 1 <sup>new</sup> </li>
   <li> text 1 <sup>new</sup> </li>
   <li> text 1 <sup>new</sup> </li>
   <li> large text <sup>new</sup> </li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeetjh/pfsonm8d/1/)

how i fix this.

Comment: you have given width for the `ul` and `li` remove the `width` it will work fine or add `display:inline-block` the take the `width` of larger `li` demo - https://jsfiddle.net/pfsonm8d/5/

Comment: Why you define your ul  and li width

Comment: I need width of ul li

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with adding a width to `ul` refer below for fiddle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shanaka/pfsonm8d/4/)

You can either remove width of `ul` or simple add as follows.

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your width values to with:100%;

```
 ul {
      width: 100%;
    }
    ul li {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set max-width to li  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q31fx3cu/)

css

```
li {
    max-width: 62px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works well without the `width` attribute:

https://jsfiddle.net/pfsonm8d/7/